# Will this be enough to make me fit

Tags: running, weight-loss, exercise, diet, swimming

height : 5 foot 4, 1.63 m

weight : roughly around 69 kg

I am really active now. I go play football/soccer every weekend for like 2 hours. I also walk around 30-40 mins a day. But most of the day I sit. I am a student in a high school if that information is relevant. I also plan to go running early morning at 5:30 on weekdays. I run like 20 mins and then I go swimming after jogging. I swim at a moderate pace 500m-700m in 30 mins. All this is done on days I dont go to play football.

I don't know what I eat everyday but here is a an average day.

- breakfast: Milo balls, cornflakes, or 2 roti with fish and always hot black tea
- snack: A yoghurt or a biscuit (the junk food kind)
- lunch: Rice with pan seared fish covered in chili paste, 3 roti with fish or chickpeas, or fish and potatoes with steamed vegetables.
- evening: black tea with bread and chocolate, hazelnut, or some spread or toast with jam
- at night: i drink some hot beverage and eat a little snack

With all this information provided, **is this all enough for me to lose a few kilograms in a few months?** I don't want to be thin, i just want to be fit.

Comment: Unless very obese you shouldn't focus on weight loss at your age, just fitness and healthy eating. You haven't given enough information to determine if you even should lose weight, as BMI charts are useless. You train a lot, and I suggest that you read books and watch YouTube videos about cooking and working out to help make your training more effective.

Comment: Hard to answer, but tracking programs might help. Endomondo is an app that has some good calorie calculations for many different types of exercises. This combined with daily weight checks in the morning before doing anything can help you decide if your eating too much. Then the only missing piece of the puzzle is the calories eaten. There are other posts about this topic that might help too. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the roti is made from whole-wheat flour, the rice should be brown rice and the bread should be whole grain bread. Also, make sure you eat at least 400 grams of vegetables during the day.

The exercise you do should have sufficient intensity, you should measure how fast you run during that 20 minutes. If the pace is slower than about 13 km/h then you should run for a shorter time at a faster pace and gradually increase the running time until you can run for 20 minutes at a pace faster than 13 km/h, and then increase the time to 30 minutes, 40 minutes, etc. until you are able to run an hour at this pace (and that at least 5 times per week). But it can take a few years of hard exercise to get there.